# python + SQLAlchemy: deleting with the Session object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't quite figure this out: I'd like to delete all the records from a table on a matching query. Kind of like this.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(string)
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
meta.reflect(bind=engine, schema='myschema')

Base = automap_base(metadata=meta)
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
Classes = Base.classes

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

session.delete(plays.record_id == '123')
```

But that isn't working. What's the idea here? Error I get is:

`error in parsing record ID 020087: Class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression' is not mapped`

Answer (score 109):

In SQL Alchemy you are deleting Objects that you get with a query from the database. This you can do in 2 Ways:

Deleting with query (will issue just one `DELETE` statement):

```
session.query(User).filter(User.id==7).delete()
session.commit()
```

Deleting object instance returned by a query (will issue 2 statements: first `SELECT`, then `DELETE`):

```
obj=session.query(User).filter(User.id==7).first()
session.delete(obj)
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 33):

---

**Delete All Records**

```
#for all records
session.query(Model).delete()
session.commit()
```

**Deleted Single Row**

If you want to delete specific records then try `filter` clause in the query.
ex.

```
#for specific value
session.query(Model).filter(Model.id==123).delete()
session.commit()
```

**Delete Single Record by Object**

```
record_obj = session.query(Model).filter(Model.id==123).first()
session.delete(record_obj)
session.commit()
```

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#deleting-records

Comment: You saved me brother. Thanks for sharing your skills. With your help I was able to delete all records in associate table when all records from parent are removed from Database (many to many relationship)

Answer (score 0):

**Delete Multiple Records**

```
session.query(User).where(User.id.in_([1,2,3,4])).delete()
session.commit()
```